# Call by reference in C

Tags: c

In the classic swap function, when we pass in two pointers, the values the pointers point to will swap. However in this simple function

```
int leng (char *a)
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; *a!='\0'; a++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

After the function is called, the pointer still points to the first element of the array instead of the last element. Why is that? How is it different from the swap function?

Comment: See http://c-faq.com/ptrs/passptrinit.html

Comment: This question has surely been asked by hundreds before you.

Comment: Please check FAQs before asking questions

Comment: In the implementation of your classic swap function, you *dereference* the pointer values and modify the values *pointed to* by your input pointers.  Here, you do no such thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A pointer is itself an object. In this case, you are passing the pointer by value, not by reference, so any changes to the pointer itself will not be reflected outside the function. If you were to change the object the pointer points to in the function, those changes would persist outside the function.

Try:

```
int leng (char** a)
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; **a!='\0'; (*a)++)
        n++;
    return n;
}

leng(&pointer);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing in a pointer by value.  The pointer value is copied on to the stack during the function call.  You are incrementing that stack variable, which then goes away when the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the same as the `swap` function: the `swap` function lets you change the values that are pointed-to, but it doesn't let you change the pointers themselves. Likewise, `leng` can change the characters in the string that `a` points to, but changes to `a` itself — changing it to point to a different array element — will not be seen by the caller.

If you wanted to change that, you could do so by writing:

```
int leng (char **a)
{
    int n;
    for (n=0; **a!='\0'; *a++)
        n++;
    return n;
}
```

and pass in a pointer *to* `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want a pointer-to-a-pointer, not just a regular pointer. (Pointers themselves are passed by value, you're changing the value of the copy of the pointer passed in).